# WCF Service not Processing MSMQ Message

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a WCF Windows Service that checks for MSMQ messages.
It picks the messages up ok but the ProcessMSMQMessage event does not seem to get called.

Any ideas why this is? Have I set ProcessMSMQMessage event correctly? Or am I missing something?

My code is below. Thanks.

WCF Service Class...

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{

  private ServiceHost host;

  public MyService()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
    string queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessMsgQueueName"];
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
    {
      MessageQueue thisQueue = MessageQueue.Create(queueName, true);
      thisQueue.SetPermissions("Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.ReceiveMessage);
    }

    try
    {
      Uri serviceUri = new Uri("msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:" + queueName);

      // communicate to MSMQ how to transfer and deliver the messages
      MsmqIntegrationBinding serviceBinding = new MsmqIntegrationBinding();
      serviceBinding.Security.Transport.MsmqAuthenticationMode = MsmqAuthenticationMode.None;
      serviceBinding.Security.Transport.MsmqProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;

      serviceBinding.SerializationFormat = MsmqMessageSerializationFormat.Binary;

      host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService.Service1)); // add watcher class name
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService.IService1), serviceBinding, serviceUri);
      host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      EventLog.WriteEntry("SERVICE" + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
    if (host != null)
     host.Close();
  }
}
```

IService1 Contract...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "MyService")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Events.Dashboard_Message))]
public interface IService1
{
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void ProcessMSMQMessage(MsmqMessage<Events.Dashboard_Message> msg);
}
```

Service1 Class...

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
  [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
  public void ProcessMSMQMessage(MsmqMessage<Events.Dashboard_Message> msg)
  {
    string msgName = msg.GetType().Name;

    // send to eventlog
    EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService", msgName);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it working finally!!

Issue was in IService1 contract. Needed to add Action = "*" to below

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]

Comment: I get this... Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
 •Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 17 minutes. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: That's fine. The error message tells you what happened. There is a time restraint put on users, depending on your reputation. In the meantime. this limit has expired and now you can put the answer into a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working finally.

The issue was in IService1 contract. Needed to add `Action = "*"`.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
```